# Multiple jumbotrons inside a container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a page with 3 jumbotrons and a bunch of other content in between. In my _Layout, I am currently calling `@RenderBody` inside a container to get everything displayed. However, the jumbotrons are not the full width of the screen because they are also in the container. My question is: How can I get the jumbotrons to be full screen width while keeping the contents inside the container?

I've tried a hacky solution where I partitioned my HTML into sections and then separately render them using `@RenderSection` inside or outside a container depending on what it is. This isn't a very elegant solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show us a stripped down version of the relevant generated html?

Comment: I think the short answer here is that you cannot, you will need to move the jumbotrons outside of the container. Your render sections whilst not elegant is probably the solution.